# GitHub - Contributor count still 1?

Tags: git, github

I'm still new to Github and trying to learn more advanced features. So I've decided to make a dummy Github account where I can simulate a team collaborating on a single project.

What I did was:

1. Make a repo on my main account called `my-first-repo`
2. Push my local repo to it (w/ some commits)
3. I've added my dummy account as `collaborator`via Github settings/collaborators.
4. From my dummy account, I've clone main account's repo on other PC.
5. Made some commits and pushed it (access granted)

I can see my dummy account's commits on main/online repo.

Now the question is:
Why is the `contributor` still count as 1? (even though I can see dummy account in its commits graph)

Also, I'm wondering why should I go for adding a member as collaborator instead of just owning my own repo and just let them send pull request?

EDIT: added screenshot for clearer question: http://prntscr.com/9vbnwg (as you can see, contributor is still 1 instead of 2)

EDIT 2: added more screenshot http://prntscr.com/9vbx2s (as you can see, my dummy account can commit on my main/online repo, yet repo contributor still counts as 1)

Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - maybe it's because you didn't link your email: you have to 1) set your email in git (in the command line) and 2) make sure your email address is added to your Github account.

https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/

Comment: hello, yes I did linked my email as `git config --global user.email "my dummy email" 

im just not sure about your second instruction and how to do that? thanks!

Comment: Try this: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/

Comment: as for your 2nd instruction, ive tried to put my dummy email to my main account (settings/emails/add) but it says that my dummy email is already in use. its an error.

Comment: Oops, I meant that you should put your dummy email in your dummy account, not your main account!

Comment: im sorry i failed to understand what you meant by that? on my other pc, ive got `git config --global user.email "my dummy email"`

Comment: and on my main github account, i was trying to put my dummy email thru settings/email/add but github says its already in use and my repo contributor still count as 1 :/

Comment: please see my question EDIT 2. Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm, sorry - if your email is set up using `git config --global user.email $DUMMY_EMAIL` and your dummy Github account has the same dummy email associated with it... I'm not sure what the problem is. :/

Comment: thanks. but can i add your github on my repo as collab and see if that reproduce the same prob?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the contributor count has just added my dummy account! I didn't do anything. I just waited! lol. I didn't know it will take some time before such repo updates reflects on itself.

But anyway, at least my problem is solved.

Thanks!